# Uncorrelatedness does not implie independence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution, independence

Let $X∼N(μ,σ^2)$ and $Y= 1−X^2$ be two real-valued r.v. How do I proof that $Cov(X,Y)=0$ but $X,Y$ not independent?

Comment: Are you having trouble showing that covariance is zero, or dependence?  There doesn’t seem much effort here.

Comment: It is clear by the definition of $Y$ that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent. What have you tried in terms of showing zero covariance?

Comment: My Trouble is with the independence especially.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1215352/148510) should help.

Comment: @RRL, what do you mean?

Comment: Is covariance actually zero? Quick math yielded $-2\mu \sigma^2$ for me

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to see that $X$ and $Y$ are independent is by considering for any $t\in\mathbb R$ the probability
$$
\mathbb P(X>t,Y<1-t^2),
$$
which obviously equals $\mathbb P(X>t)$ since $X>t$ implies that $Y<1-t^2$.

On the other hand, suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Then
$$
\mathbb P(X>t,Y<1-t^2)=\mathbb P(X>t)\mathbb P(Y<1-t^2).
$$
Comparing this with the first equation, it follows that $\mathbb P(Y<1-t^2)=1$ for all $t\in\mathbb R$, which means that $\mathbb P(Y=-\infty)=1$ which is a contradiction. Thus $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.