# How do you compute multivariate normal distribution probabilities?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Given a vector $$ X = (X1,X2,X3)^t $$ which is multivariate normal
with mean 0 and covariance matrix $$  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 3 \end{array} \right) $$

find 
$$
P(X1 > X2 + X3 +2)
$$

I dont think anything involving the pdf is the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $X_1-X_2-X_3$ is normally distributed. What are its mean and variance? (See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/115518/215011) for the variance of a sum of correlated RVs.)

Comment: ah! of course, thanks!